# Dual of the cross is the cross of the duals.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let E,F be normed spaces. Prove that $ (E\times F)^´ = E^´ \times F^´ $

(Note that the superscript $ ´$ denotes the dual space of the normed space.)

I have a hint that if we can show that $ T: E^´ \times F^´ \rightarrow  (E\times F)^´$  defined by  $  T(g,f)(x,y) = g(x) + f(y) $ for $ g \in E^´ , f\in F^´ , x\in E , y\in F,$ is isometric isomorphism, we are done. And also norm $ \alpha $ is defined as $ \alpha((g,h)) = max\{\alpha(g), \alpha(f)\} $

Linearity,continuity and injectivity of $T$ is obvious. I can handle it. But ontoness of $T$, continuity of inverse map and norm-isometry are the points where  I got stuck.

For isometry $(\alpha(T) = \alpha ((g,f)) )$, I tried following,

$$ \alpha(T(g,f)) \leq |T(g,f)(x,y) | =|g(x)+ f(y) | \leq  |g(x)|+|f(y)| $$
Without loss off generality, take $ max\{(\alpha(g), \alpha(f))\}=\alpha(f) $
$$  |g(x)|+|f(y)| \leq 2 \alpha(f)$$

I could not deduce from that $ \alpha(T) < \alpha(f)$ for one side of the isometry.

Comment: The inverse is just the following: every $\varphi \in (E \times F)'$ defines $e \mapsto \varphi(e,0)$ and $f \mapsto \varphi(0,f)$, i.e. elements of $E',F'$ respectively.

Comment: So you're setup must satisfy  $ \varphi T(e,f) = (e,f) .$ However, $\varphi (e+f) = \varphi((e,0) + (0,f)) = e+f \ne (e,f)$

Comment: But @MichałMiśkiewicz , tthis is possible if you define $\varphi(e,0) = (e,0) $

Answer (score 0):

We have $T \colon E' \times F' \to (E \times F)'$ defined by $T(\varphi_E,\varphi_F)(e,f) = \varphi_E(e)+\varphi_F(f)$.

In the other direction, let $S_E \colon (E \times F)' \to E'$ be defined by $S_E(\varphi)(e) = \varphi(e,0)$, similarly $S_F(\varphi)(f) = \varphi(0,f)$. This pair defines $S \colon (E \times F)' \to E' \times F'$ by $S(\varphi) = (S_E(\varphi),S_F(\varphi))$. Both $S,T$ are linear and continuous, so we only need to prove that $ST = id$, $TS = id$.

For any $(\varphi_E,\varphi_F) \in E' \times F'$, 
$$ S_E(T(\varphi_E,\varphi_F))(e) = T(\varphi_E,\varphi_F)(e,0) = \varphi_E(e)+\varphi_F(0) = \varphi_E(e), $$
showing $ST = id$.

For any $\varphi \in (E \times F)'$, 
$$ T(S(\varphi))(e,f) = S_E(\varphi)(e)+S_F(\varphi)(f) = \varphi(e,0)+\varphi(0,f) = \varphi(e,f), $$
showing $TS = id$.

All of this follows from tracing the definitions of dual maps to projections $(e,f) \mapsto e$ and embeddings $e \mapsto (e,0)$.

Comment: O.K . This is very clear to me.  The only part remaining is  T being norm-isometry. In other words , $ || T|| = ||  (\varphi_E, \varphi_F || :=\operatorname{max}\{ || \varphi_E  ||  , || \varphi_F   ||  \} $